# How can I set the value of objectID in algolia rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, indexing, algolia

I am using algolia gem in my rails app.  I am currently combining 3 different models into one index for a combined search of our case studies, blog posts and videos.

I am having trouble as indexing one model will overwrite objects from another model as Algolia appears to use the rails generated ID to map to objectID column.

## posts.rb

```
algoliasearch auto_index: false, if: :open?, index_name: "combined_#{Rails.env}" do
    attribute :objectID do
      "p#{id}"
    end
end
```

## video.rb and case_studies.rb

In the same fashion I try to set `attribute :objectID to "v#{id}"` for videos as well as set `attribute :objectID to "c#{id}"` for case studies

This virtual attribute style did not work, so I attempted to create an actual string column on the db and reindex that way to no avail.

If anyone have any ideas here I would really appreciate it and I am running low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [custom ObjectID](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails#custom-objectid) inside each of your Model.

**Inside your model**

```
def custom_algolia_id
  "v#{id}"
end

algoliasearch id: :custom_algolia_id do
  attribute :title, :length
end
```